# Stubbed response not available in application

Tags: cypress, apollo-client

I have a test where I intercept, stub, and wait for a GraphQL request. In Cypress I can see that the request was intercepted and clicking on it logs the stubbed response, however, in the application the response is undefined.

I'm stubbing a request generated using `useQuery` hook from Apollo Client.

```js
/* spec */
describe('Users', function () {
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.intercept('POST', '/v1/graphql', (req) => {
            if (hasOperationName(req, 'Users')) {
                req.alias = 'users'

                req.reply({
                    data: {
                        users: [{ id: '1' }],
                    },
                })
            }
        })
    })

    it('Should show users', () => {
        cy.visit('/account')
        cy.wait('@users')

        cy.get('[data-cy="user-card"]').should('exist')
    })
})
```

When I click on the request from the Cypress logs, this is what it logs to the browser console.

[image: cypress activity log]

[image: browser log]

But when I log in the application code, the response is undefined.

```js
/* application code */

const {data, error} = useQuery(UsersQuery) // data and error both are undefined here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Apollo Client looks like it verifies that the signature of the response and query match, in my case the stubbed response didn't match the query signature.

Updated the stubbed response to match the query signature and I can now see it in my application code.

Answer (score 0):

`useQuery` is a hook, not a synchronous function. Use the `loading` result to see if the query is still running.

```
const {data, error, loading } = useQuery(UsersQuery);
if (loading) {
…
} else if (data) {
… data will be available
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Michel. This happened when loading was false too. 

I figured it out though, Apollo Client looks like it verifies that the signature of the response and query match, in my case the stubbed response didn't match the query signature.